# How to upgrade from one version of Cyanogenmod to another?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am fairly new to rooting / putting custom ROMs on devices; I finally have my phone in a state that I like, after putting Cyanogenmod 7 on my HTC Desire Z. Since I've done this, there have been a few point releases, and a minor release is not far away. However, I don't really know how to upgrade from one version to another (and I couldn't find any instructions on how to do so).

How do I upgrade from one version of Cyanogenmod to another? Is it the same process as installing it in the first place? Will I have to wipe all the data on my phone, as I did the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyanogenmod 11 has a built-in mechanism for checking for updates.

Go to `Settings -> About Phone -> CyanogenMod updates`
There you can toggle when your device will query for an update and on what release channel (Release and Development being Stable and Nightly respectively).

When an update will appear click on it's icon to download and Install, from there, it will do everything for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can basically upgrade the same way as the original installation (flash the new ROM from recovery).

The general rule is: Do a complete wipe for major releases, but just clear the caches for minor releases.  See [this CM forum topic](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/15366-how-to-upgrade-between-nightlies-without-loss-of-settings/).

Comment: This question is old and newer versions of CM have a self updating feature, I've added a new answer